# Polygon shapefile layer shows NoData for Identify in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, attribute-table, arcgis-9.3, identify

I have a soil survey polygon map with each polygon representing a soil type.

If I examine the attribute table of the layer, I can see what each polygon represents.

If I select a row in the attribute table it highlights the proper polygon on the map.

If I convert this layer to a raster, ArcMap colors each polygon according to it's correct soil type.

However, when I use Identify on one of these polygons it reports NoData and shows a blank table.

So it seems the attribute are not being reflected on the map itself.

Any idea of the cause and/or how to fix?

[image]

Comment: You converted the vector to raster -- In what format?  At what bit depth? How did you map polygon attributes to raster values?  It would probably help if you include a graphic that shows the raster on top of the polygon layer and denotes where the Identity tool was clicked.

BTW: ArcGIS 9.x was Retired in Dec 2013, and even 10.0 will be Retired in a few weeks.  If you're going to be starting GIS, using something released this decade is advised.

Comment: I'd also note that the graphic shows NoData for the *raster*, not the polygon layer.

Comment: As a new user please take the 2-minute [Tour] to learn more about our focussed Q&A format.  What you are observing here is the software working correctly.  The misunderstanding seems to relate to using Identify to identify from a raster and expecting to see polygon attributes returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identify tool yields a result for the layer(s) selected in the drop down list on the right of "identify from:" . In your case, the selected layer is currently "orange_soil_raster" and not "durh_soil_utm". Change the identify target to "all visible layers" or "durh_soil_utm" and it will work. Note that in the first case you will need to expand the results for your layer of interest.

Comment: Ah. I'm used to it just being the top most layer. Good eye. Thanks!!